# Hibernate Spring PostgreSQL: no transaction is in progress Hibernate commands work, JpaRepository save method doesn't save entity in database ignored

Tags: java, spring, postgresql, hibernate, spring-mvc

I have a simple `Dog` entity:

**Dog.java**:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "dogs")
public class Dog {
    public Dog()  {}

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;

    @Column
    private String name;

    public Long getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(Long id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }
}
```

**DogController.java**:

```
@RestController
public class DogController {
    @Autowired
    private DogRepository dogRepository;

    @RequestMapping("/api/dogs/insert/default")
    @Transactional
    public String insertDefault()  {
        Dog dog = new Dog();
        dog.setName("Alpha dog");
        dogRepository.save(dog);
        return "dog inserted OK";
    }
}
```

**DogRepository**:

```
@Repository
public interface DogRepository extends JpaRepository<Dog, Long> {
}
```

However when I go to `/api/dogs/insert/default` it simply displays `dog inserted OK` without changing a database or even attempting to change it (no queries are printed to the console).

What could be the problem here? In debugger I can see that `dogRepository` is not null.

My `WebMvcConfigurer` class looks like this:

```
@EnableWebMvc
@Configuration
@EnableJpaRepositories("testproject")
@EnableTransactionManagement
@ComponentScan("testproject")
public class WebConfig implements WebMvcConfigurer {...}
```

I tried adding the `@EnableTransactionManagement` to it, but it didn't work

**EDIT**:

I don't have an `application.properties` file. All properties are configured using Java classes.

**DbConfig.java**:

```
@Configuration
 @EnableTransactionManagement
@EnableJpaRepositories(basePackages = "testproject", entityManagerFactoryRef = "entityManagerFactory")
 public class DbConfig {
    @Bean
    public LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean entityManagerFactory() {
        LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean entityManagerFactoryBean = new LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean();
        entityManagerFactoryBean.setDataSource(getDatasource());
        entityManagerFactoryBean.setPersistenceProviderClass(HibernatePersistenceProvider.class);

        entityManagerFactoryBean.setJpaProperties(getHibernateProperties());

        entityManagerFactoryBean.setPackagesToScan("testproject");

        return entityManagerFactoryBean;
    }


    @Bean
    public DataSource getDatasource() {
        DriverManagerDataSource dataSource = new DriverManagerDataSource();
        dataSource.setDriverClassName("org.postgresql.Driver");
        dataSource.setUrl("jdbc:postgresql://127.0.0.1:5432/testproject");
        dataSource.setUsername("postgres");
        dataSource.setPassword("bigfalcon");
        return dataSource;
    }

    @Bean
    public SessionFactory getSessionFactory() throws IOException {
        LocalSessionFactoryBean sessionFactoryBean = new LocalSessionFactoryBean();
        sessionFactoryBean.setPackagesToScan("testproject");
        //getHibernateProperties method is a private method

        sessionFactoryBean.setHibernateProperties(getHibernateProperties());
        sessionFactoryBean.setDataSource(getDatasource());
        sessionFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet();

        return sessionFactoryBean.getObject();
    }

    @Bean(name = "transactionManager")
    public HibernateTransactionManager getTransactionManager() throws IOException {
        HibernateTransactionManager transactionManager = new HibernateTransactionManager();
        transactionManager.setSessionFactory(getSessionFactory());
        return transactionManager;
    }


    @Bean
    private static Properties getHibernateProperties() {
        Properties hibernateProperties = new Properties();  //PostgreSQLDialect
        //hibernateProperties.put("hibernate.dialect", "org.hibernate.dialect.HSQLDialect");
        hibernateProperties.put("hibernate.dialect", "org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQLDialect");
        hibernateProperties.put("hibernate.show_sql", true);
    //    hibernateProperties.put("spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto", "create");

        hibernateProperties.put( "hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto", "create-drop");
         /*hibernateProperties.setProperty(
                "hibernate.dialect", "org.hibernate.dialect.H2Dialect");
*/
        System.out.println();
        // other properties
        return hibernateProperties;
    }
}
```

**EDIT**:

Using the same `dogRepository` to **select** existing dogs from the database (which I manually inserted) works fine:

```
 @RequestMapping("/api/dogs/view/all")
    public Iterable<Dog> viewDogs()  {
        Iterable<Dog> dogs = dogRepository.findAll(); //non-null size, returns a JSON with dogs
        return dogs;
    }
```

**EDIT**: Maven dependencies:

```
<dependencies>

    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework.security/spring-security-core -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-security-core</artifactId>
        <version>5.3.1.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework/spring-webmvc -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-webmvc</artifactId>
        <version>5.2.5.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework/spring-web -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-web</artifactId>
        <version>5.2.5.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework.security/spring-security-core -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-security-core</artifactId>
        <version>5.3.1.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework.security/spring-security-config -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-security-config</artifactId>
        <version>5.3.1.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework.security/spring-security-web -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-security-web</artifactId>
        <version>5.3.1.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework.data/spring-data-jpa -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.data</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-data-jpa</artifactId>
        <version>2.2.6.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>


    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework/spring-core -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-core</artifactId>
        <version>5.2.5.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.thymeleaf</groupId>
        <artifactId>thymeleaf</artifactId>
        <version>3.0.7.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.thymeleaf</groupId>
        <artifactId>thymeleaf-spring4</artifactId>
        <version>3.0.7.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>


    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.opennlp</groupId>
        <artifactId>opennlp-tools</artifactId>
        <version>1.9.1</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/net.dv8tion/JDA -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>net.dv8tion</groupId>
        <artifactId>JDA</artifactId>
        <version>4.0.0_46</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.hibernate/hibernate-core -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId>
        <version>5.4.4.Final</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.h2database/h2 -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.h2database</groupId>
        <artifactId>h2</artifactId>
        <version>1.4.197</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>

    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework/spring-orm -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-orm</artifactId>
        <version>5.2.5.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.postgresql</groupId>
        <artifactId>postgresql</artifactId>
        <version>9.4-1203-jdbc4</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/javax.servlet/javax.servlet-api -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
        <artifactId>javax.servlet-api</artifactId>
        <version>4.0.1</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>

    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework.security.oauth/spring-security-oauth2 -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.security.oauth</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-security-oauth2</artifactId>
        <version>2.4.1.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>

    <!--is needed for jwt-->
    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/javax.xml/jaxb-api -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.xml</groupId>
        <artifactId>jaxb-api</artifactId>
        <version>2.1</version>
    </dependency>


    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.sun.xml.bind/jaxb-impl -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.sun.xml.bind</groupId>
        <artifactId>jaxb-impl</artifactId>
        <version>3.0.0-M4</version>
    </dependency>


    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.sun.xml.bind/jaxb-core -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.sun.xml.bind</groupId>
        <artifactId>jaxb-core</artifactId>
        <version>3.0.0-M4</version>
    </dependency>


    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework.security/spring-security-jwt -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-security-jwt</artifactId>
        <version>1.1.0.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/io.jsonwebtoken/jjwt -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>io.jsonwebtoken</groupId>
        <artifactId>jjwt</artifactId>
        <version>0.9.1</version>
    </dependency>


    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.jakewharton.fliptables/fliptables -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.jakewharton.fliptables</groupId>
        <artifactId>fliptables</artifactId>
        <version>1.0.2</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.squareup.okhttp3</groupId>
        <artifactId>okhttp</artifactId>
        <version>3.4.2</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.json/json -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.json</groupId>
        <artifactId>json</artifactId>
        <version>20190722</version>
    </dependency>



    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
        <artifactId>jstl</artifactId>
        <version>1.2</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
        <artifactId>jackson-databind</artifactId>
        <version>2.9.8</version>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

**EDIT**:

I also tried to get it to update the entity:

```
@RequestMapping("/api/dogs/update/{id}")
public Iterable<Dog> updateDog(@PathVariable("id") long id)  {
    Optional<Dog> dog = dogRepository.findById(id);
    Dog dogValue = dog.get();
    dogValue.setName("New name");
    dogRepository.save(dogValue);
    return dogRepository.findAll();
}
```

which however doesn't work: the JSON returned to the browser contains updated name (`New name`), but doesn't update the database itself.

**EDIT**:

## I managed to get it to work with manual Hibernate commands, see the added methods `insertDog(Dog dog)` and `updateDog(Dog dog)`: I take the `Session` object from autowired `DbConfig` object and use `session.save(dog)`, `session.flush()` to update the database. With the following controller code both `/api/dogs/insert/default` and `/api/dogs/update/3/Buddy` work fine.

So the problem seems to be related to `JpaRepository` specifically, seeing as if I forego using it and write the Hibernate code myself, it works fine:

**DogController.java**:

```
@CrossOrigin
@RestController
@Transactional(  readOnly = false)
public class DogController {
    @Autowired
    private DogRepository dogRepository;

    @Autowired
    private DbConfig dbConfig;

    @RequestMapping("/api/dogs/insert/default")
    @Transactional(readOnly=false)
    public String insertDefault() throws Exception {
        Dog dog = new Dog();
        dog.setName("Alpha dog");
        //dogRepository.save(dog);
        insertDog(dog);
        return "dog inserted OK";
    }

    @RequestMapping("/api/dogs/view/all")
    public Iterable<Dog> viewDogs()  {
        Iterable<Dog> dogs = dogRepository.findAll();
        return dogs;
    }

    @RequestMapping("/api/dogs/update/{id}/{name}")
    public Iterable<Dog> updateDog(@PathVariable("id") long id,
                                @PathVariable("name") String name)  throws Exception  {
        Optional<Dog> dog = dogRepository.findById(id);
        Dog dogValue = dog.get();
        dogValue.setName(name);
        //dogRepository.save(dogValue);
        Session session = dbConfig.getSessionFactory().openSession();
        updateDog(dogValue);
        return dogRepository.findAll();
    }

    public void updateDog(Dog dog) throws Exception  {
        Session session = dbConfig.getSessionFactory().openSession();
        session.beginTransaction();

        session.merge(dog);
        session.flush();
        session.getTransaction().commit();
        session.clear();
        session.close();
    }


    public boolean insertDog(Dog dog)  throws Exception  {
        boolean result = false;

        Session session = dbConfig.getSessionFactory().openSession();
        session.beginTransaction();
        try {
            session.save(dog);
            session.flush();
            session.getTransaction().commit();

            result = true;
        }
        catch (Exception e)  {
            result = false;
        }
        finally  {
            session.clear();
            session.close();
        }

        return result;
    }
}
```

**EDIT**:

I wonder if something to do with generating ids of the `Dog` entity could be the problem. I use PostgreSQL and in the logs I see

```
WARN [RMI TCP Connection(2)-127.0.0.1] org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper$StandardWarningHandler.logWarning sequence "hibernate_sequence" does not exist, skipping
```

And then when I access `/api/dogs/insert/default` in console

```
Hibernate: select nextval ('hibernate_sequence')
```

gets printed.

I tried changing `GenerationStrategy` but it didn't help. I also tried adding

```
hibernateProperties.put("hibernate.connection.driver_class", "org.postgresql.Driver");
```

to `getHibernateProperties()` method in `DbConfig.java` but it didn't seem to help either.

**EDIT**:

I also tried changing `HibernateTransactionManager` to `JpaTransactionManager` in `transactionManager()` method in `DbConfig.java`:

```
 @Bean(name = "transactionManager")
     public JpaTransactionManager transactionManager() throws IOException {
        JpaTransactionManager transactionManager = new JpaTransactionManager();
        //transactionManager.setSessionFactory(getSessionFactory());
        return transactionManager;
    }
```

but that resulted the

```
NoUniqueBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type 'javax.persistence.EntityManagerFactory' available: more than one 'primary' bean found among candidates: [entityManagerFactory, getSessionFactory]
```

error on server startup

I also figured that maybe `JpaRepository` can't generate the id, so I tried making it manual:

```
@Id
@Column(name = "dog_id", unique = true, nullable = false)
private Long id;
```

and in **DogController.java**:

```
@RequestMapping("/api/dogs/insert/default")
    @Transactional(readOnly=false, propagation =  Propagation.REQUIRED)
    public String insertDefault() throws Exception {
        Dog dog = new Dog();
        Random random = new Random();
        dog.setId((long) random.nextInt(1000_000_000));
        dog.setName("Alpha dog");
        dogRepository.save(dog);
        dogRepository.flush();
        //insertDog(dog);
        return "dog inserted OK";
    }
```

however it resulted in error:

```
org.springframework.web.util.NestedServletException: 
Request processing failed; nested exception is org.springframework.dao.InvalidDataAccessApiUsageException: 
no transaction is in progress; nested exception is javax.persistence.TransactionRequiredException: no transaction is in progress
```

**EDIT**:

## Also I figured out why there was no  `no transaction is in progress` error earlier (that error helped understand what was wrong): the error only appeared after I added

```
dogRepository.flush();
```

to `DogController.java`.

If I remove `dogRepository.flush()` the `dogRepository.save(dog)` method still wouldn't work, but no visible error would appear (other than `Hibernate: select nextval ('hibernate_sequence')` in console).

## I managed to make `JpaRepository` insert on `/api/dogs/insert/default` work!

What it took: adding

```
hibernateProperties.put("hibernate.allow_update_outside_transaction",  true);
```

to `getHibernateProperties()` method of `DbConfig.java` class.

However I'm not sure that's a correct way to handle it? And if there are better methods of dealing with that error? And why that error only appeared when I use `JpaRepository` for inserting/updating entities, while if I use raw Hibernate commands (`session.save()`) the error didn't appear and updates worked fine?

Comment: Enable debug mode on spring/spring-jpa and see what's happening. You can set that on your spring boot application.properteis or yaml. or Step through the code - you might reach an ex

Comment: Nothing here suggests any problems, it's probably something in your properties.

Comment: @AneeshVijendran I don't have an `application.properities`. The tables are created and dropped on server startup just fine. So it must be either something with insert query specifically or with the `JpaRepository` itself? It feels like the `.save` command is simply ignored - I used debugger but didn't notice anything that would have hinted at the reason behind the problem

Comment: If you are using maven or gradle can you share your pom or gradle dependencies?

Comment: It is a very long post but if I understand correctly you are debugging to find the value. But hibernate will not issue the database call until you are outside of the `insertDefault` transactional default method.  so update the method to return the Id ```dogRepository.save(dog).getId();``` to postman

Answer (score 0):

Transactional is read-only by default. Write queries fails silently.

Set your annotation as `@Transactional(readOnly=false)`

Comment: Idea Intellij highlights it as redundant - implying the default value is false. I tried it, but the dog is still not inserted; also - if it couldn't change database by default - the `create-drop` policy that drops all tables and then re-creates them on server startup wouldn't have worked - but it does

Answer (score 0):

Your configuration is almost OK, i changed a couple of things and it works on my `Spring Boot v2.3.1.RELEASE`.

- Do you need this class `public class WebConfig implements WebMvcConfigurer {...}`? If yes consider annotating either `public LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean entityManagerFactory()` or this `public SessionFactory getSessionFactory() throws IOException {` with `@Primary`. Else you will get this:

> Parameter 0 of method openEntityManagerInViewInterceptorConfigurer in
> org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.orm.jpa.JpaBaseConfiguration$JpaWebConfiguration
> required a single bean, but 2 were found:
>
> - entityManagerFactory: defined by method 'entityManagerFactory' in class path resource [.../DbConfig.class]
> - getSessionFactory: defined by method 'getSessionFactory' in class path resource [.../DbConfig.class]

- You have repeated annotations on `public class WebConfig` and `public class DbConfig`. `@Configuration` is enough on `WebConfig`.

Otherwise, it looks fine, just make sure that **everywhere** you define `testproject` as values is correct and that your `postgresql` is accessible:

```
Spring Boot v2.3.1.RELEASE:
Completed initialization in 5 ms
Hibernate: insert into dogs (name) values (?)

PostgreSQL:
postgres=# SELECT version();
                          version
------------------------------------------------------------
 PostgreSQL 12.3, compiled by Visual C++ build 1914, 64-bit
(1 row)


postgres=#
postgres=# select * from dogs;
 id |   name
----+-----------
  1 | Alpha dog
(1 row)


postgres=#
```

**P.S**: I tested with an *empty* `WebConfig` class, like so:

```
@Configuration
public class WebConfig implements WebMvcConfigurer {

}
```

Comment: Should I annotate with `@Primary` only one of them: `public LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean entityManagerFactory()` or `this public SessionFactory getSessionFactory()` or both?

Comment: And `@Configuration` on `DbConfig` **is** necessary: if I remove it I get `Unsatisfied dependency expressed through field 'authenticationManager'` error. And how you could say it's not necessary when that class literally contains configurations for database... Perhaps it works for you with all configs being empty, but my configs are not empty and I have several configs classes which I need to get to work

Comment: (1) @parsecer, right, annotate `@Primary` only on one of them. (2) I did not say `@Configuration` on `DbConfig` is NOT necessary, maybe you misunderstood what i meant. Whenever you have `@Bean` defined in your class, `@Configuration` is needed. (3) I only have `WebConfig` class empty, because you did not provide what you have configured, so i left it empty. Everything else is EXACTLY as per what you provided ;-)

Comment: Ok, then i don't know how to help you, because i am using exactly the same configuration as you and mine works. The only thing i can think of, is that you check this one more time: `just make sure that everywhere you define testproject as values is correct and that your postgresql is accessible:` and also to compare apples to apples, make sure you are using Spring Boot v2.3.1.RELEASE.